# Session Variables - Doc Request

Tags: http, session, variables

## Sessions' variables

In all web app you can get/set sessions' variables

> **PHP:**
>
> ```
> $foo = $_SESSION['myVar'];
> ```
>
> **.NET** (MVC, in Controller):
>
> ```
> using System.Web.Mvc;
> // ...
> var foo = Session["myVar"];
> ```

I am looking for some detailed informations on sessions' variables :

- Their initial purpose (what problems did they aimed to address ?)
- Common use cases

---

### Storage

- **Where is it stored** on the system ?

Hard drive, RAM, ...

- **Who is storing it**?

Client / Server

- I guess it's server-side, so **what is managing it** ?

Web Server (Apache, IIS, ...) / Web App

- What is the lifetime of a session's variable ?

The session, right. So when do a session start, when does it end and how do the system know when it can get rid of these variables (GC mechanism) ?

---

### Security

- Known security flaws ?

---

*PS: I would like to allow people here to build a good documentation about this concept. Feel free to edit the question if you think some questions should be added or edited.*

Comment: The storage and security questions are specific to the implementation and therefore cannot be answered in a general case. Even with reference to specific implementations a competent answer would run to several pages thousand words.

Comment: I think your point should be part of the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Purpose**

Session Variables were created primarily to deal with the stateless behavior of the HTTP protocol. Because each page request was handled pretty much completely separately from each other page request, developers wanted ways to tie strings of requests together. The canonical example of this is a login page that authenticates the user and then changes the behavior of pages requested after login.

To help with this problem, many languages and/or frameworks provided the concept of a Session Variable which would let the developer store data that would be associated with a specific browser and would persist across separate requests from that same browser.

So, to take logins as an example, on the first request from a new browser, the Session Variable would be blank. Then the user would fill out authentication information and assuming it was correct, on the server side the code would set the Session Variable for that browser to contain some sort of identifier to say that his browser was authenticated. Then during subsequent requests the code could check that identifier in the Session Variable to do some specific code that required logging in.

Another common use case would be for a "wizard" workflow. You might have a multi-page form that you want the user to fill in over several separate requests. As the user fills out the form, you can add the values to the session until the user gets to the end of the form at which time you could save it in some more permanent storage.

**Storage and Management**

There are many ways to store Session Variables. Any sort of persistent storage that is persistent across requests will work. Probably the most basic way is to just create a separate file for each session. PHP does this by taking a session ID that it has stored as a cookie in a browser and then looks for a file with a named derived from the session ID.

You can also store Session Variables in databases, shared memory, or even in the cookie itself. Ruby on Rails stores Session Variables by encrypting  the data and then setting the cookie to the encrypted data. So the session gets stored in the user's browser itself.

Most typically the Session Variable is associated with a cookie that is stored in web browser in some way. This cookie is usually managed automatically by the language or framework that the web server application is written in. The language or framework detects a new session and creates a new Session Variable that it provides to the web server application via some sort of API. The web server application can then use the API to store information in the Session Variable, to delete it, create a new one, etc... Usually the framework has some default value for the lifetime of the session, but usually this is adjustable via the API. I think the most typical default lifetime is the the lifetime of the browser process via a cookie that has a lifetime associated with the user's browser process.

**Security**

There are a lot of security issues around Session Variables because they are typically used to manage authorization and authentication in web applications.

For example, many applications set the session lifetime just using the lifetime associated with the cookie. Many login systems want to force the user to re-login after a specified time, but you can't trust the browser to expire the cookie when you tell it to. The browser could be buggy, could be written by a malicious person, or manipulated by the user herself to adjust the lifetime of the cookie. So if the Session Variable API you are using relies on the cookie lifetime, you may need to have a secondary mechanism that forces the Session Variable to expire even if the cookie doesn't.

Some other security issues involve storage. If you store A Session ID in a cookie and then use that Session ID as your file name to store the Session Variable in, a malicious browser can change the Session ID in the cookie to another ID and then requests from that browser would start using some other browser's session file.

Another issue is stolen session information. Through XSS or packet inspection, session information can be stolen from a users browser session and then used by a malicious user to access the other user's accounts. This sort of problem is typically mitigated by using SSL to protect the session in transit.

[This page](http://php.net/manual/en/session.security.php) explains a lot of the security issues when using PHP's implementation of Session Variables. Ruby on Rails has [a similar page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) that outlines the security issues with Session Variables for that platform.

Answer (score 2):

So, I will be taking this question on under two considerations:
 1. I am answering under PHP guidelines.
 2. I am assuming that a shared hosting service is used.

**Storage**
With the use of shared hosting, the php.ini file holds this answer. The file is created, physically, at the path you specify through the "session.save_path" line within the php.ini file.

Source: [php.net Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path)

**Who Stores Session**
The session is TECHNICALLY stored by the SERVER but at request, obviously, by the client. So, answer: SERVER.
Source: [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

**Who Manages It**
If your session.save_path is set to go somewhere on a shared hosting server, then they control the GC that destroys it or ignores it until later. Actually, instances have happened for me where other clients within the shared hosting server had their session_gc.maxlifetime at a MUCH shorter amount than I did, therefore causing my session files to be destroyed in the amount of time that THEY set (other shared users). To get around this, edit your "session.save_path" to within your OWN file tree.

**Lifetime**
As said previously, "session.gc_maxlifetime" controls this file's "expiration". Along with this, the "session.gc_probability" and "session.gc_divisor" should be considered, and set to "1" and "100", respectively. Google search this for further explanation.

Source: [session.gc_maxlifetime](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)

**Security**
I'm going to let php.net handle this, but here's the link!

Source: [Security](http://php.net/manual/en/session.security.php)

Answer (score 2):

I take an ASP.NET application scenario as an example.

In ASP.NET/MVC `HttpContext.Current.Session` provides access to RAM that is managed by the Server (WebServer/AppServer, IIS). In the case of the Internet Information Server, the RAM used is located inside a so called Application Pool and used by one or more Apps running inside the Web-/AppServer. The structure from the programmer's point of view is a Dictionary which means for access via C# that you can use the this[] operator to write to and read from the Session object.

```
// write access
var CurrentArticle = 123456;
Session["CurrentArticle"] = CurrentArticle;

//...

// read access
var CurrentArticle = 0;
CurrentArticle = (int)Session[nameof(CurrentArticle)];
```

The Session object provided by .NET will be created in the method `Session_Start` and deleted in `Session_End`. However, you don't have to use the System's default Session Store and can implement your own, i.e. like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Caching;
using System.Web;
// using MyOtherStuff;

namespace MyStuff.Server.Context
{
    public class HttpSessionState : HttpSessionStateBase
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> _sessionStorage = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();
        public override object this[string name]
        {
            get 
            { 
                if (HttpContext.Current == null || HttpContext.Current.Session == null) 
                    if (!_sessionStorage.ContainsKey(name))
                        return null;
                    else return _sessionStorage[name];
                return HttpContext.Current.Session[name]; 
            }
            set 
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current == null || HttpContext.Current.Session == null)
                    _sessionStorage[name] = value;
                else HttpContext.Current.Session[name] = value; 
            }
        }
    }
    public class Current
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Objects stored in Cache expire after some time; compare Application 
        /// </summary>
        public static ExpiringCache Cache = new ExpiringCache();
        /// <summary>
        /// Objects stored in Application don't expire
        /// </summary>
        public static Application Application = new Application();
        public static HttpSessionState Session = new HttpSessionState();
        private static System.Web.HttpServerUtility server;
        public static System.Web.HttpServerUtility Server
        {
            get
            {
                if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null)
                    return Context.Current.Server;
                if (server != null)
                    return server;
                server = new System.Web.HttpApplication().Server;
                if (server != null)
                    return server;
                throw new NotSupportedException("HDitem.ApplicationServices.Current was not initialized (server)");
            }
            set { server = value; }
        }
    }
    //..
}
```

Every new Browser connecting to your server creates a new session. If you don't care about the data from recent sessions of the same user (if your app has users) than you are probably done here.

If you want to re-connect a new session to one or more previous sessions, i.e. identified by some combination of data you have available about this user (e.g. through the request, a cookie or alike) or in the easiest form the authentication of the user than you might want to store the data of the session in Session_End rather than deleting it and recover it in Session_start or any time thereafter (as soon as you have enough data about the user of this session to identify her. In this case you need any form of Session Persistence (presumably this boils down to a Hard Disk or SSD to refer to your question) which in this case can come in any form of per-user-based storage, sometimes stored in a user-profile in a database or any file format like XML- or JSON-based.

So in other words: I don't want to generalize too much here but Session Storage is ideally very fast Memory Storage, potentially saved to any external storage if Session Persistence is implemented.

The above mentioned Session Storage is located on the server side. Modern browsers have a built in localstore that can be accessed via JavaScript. This local storage can also be used to create a session memory that can be used differently from the server-side session but can of course be synchronized in form of explicit requests or attachment to requests (cookie).